# Merge Property and ItemGroup that are unrelated into a single Property

Tags: msbuild-propertygroup, msbuild-itemgroup

I have a Property and an ItemGroup and I need to merge them into a single Property with a 1 to 1 relationship:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Servers>SvrA,SvrB,SvrC<Servers>
<PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <--Get full folder paths-->
    <ConfigFolders Include="$([System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories('C:\02-App', 'Folder-?'))"/>
    <--Get just the folder names: 'Folder-1;Folder-2;Folder-3'-->
    <ConfigFolderNames Include="$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName('%(ConfigFolders.FullPath)'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What do I need to do to get the end result like this?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <ServerList>SvrA,Folder-1;SvrB,Folder-2;SvrC,Folder-3</ServerList>
<PropertyGroup>
```